# How are arbitrary letters in a word or phrase made bold using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a chrome extension that will allow me to make some of the letters in a sentence or paragraph bold. I have tried using this code
`let container = document.querySelector('p');   let newtext = container.innerText.split('').map(m =>   Math.random() > .49 ?  <strong>${m}</strong> : m);  container.innerHTML = newtext.join('')`.
This was a solution provided to me by Kinglish.

It works perfectly. However, it only works for the first paragraph of the page. I have also attempted to use a `for loop` for this code - tried `querySelectorAll` but it does not seem to work.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't format words or letters, HTML and CSS (usually a combination of the two) does. You can however use JavaScript to change the HTML and CSS on the fly. For bolding, you can either use the `<b></b>` HTML tag or `font-weight: bold;` in CSS. Randomizing it is a bit more tricky because you will need to (randomly) split the string into parts that need to be bolded and parts that don't, bold the parts that need to be bolded, then concatenate everything back together.

Comment: I don't think that is the approach I would take. You cant make alterations to single characters without having to edit the HTML. That would become a mess quickly. Instead consider using a font-family replacement then you can just set the characters you want to as a bolded character. [Reference](https://css-tricks.com/modifying-specific-letters-with-css-and-javascript/) to get started.

Comment: The duplicate displayed with the closed info isn't accurate - plus is about reactjs. If the answer below doesn't help, leave a comment

Comment: Thank you for the comments and the solution, I've learned something new, and the concept of split and join. However, I do not understand why the solution is only limited to the first paragraph of a page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straightforward way using `Math.random()` as the switch. Note that I grab the reference text as `innerText` so I don't have any HTML tags to consider.

```js
let container = document.querySelector('p');
let newtext = container.innerText.split('').map(m => Math.random() > .49 ? `<strong>${m}</strong>` : m);
container.innerHTML = newtext.join('')
```

```css
strong {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```